# User (session) count in cluster

Tags: java, web-applications, spring-security, weblogic-10.x

Is there a good way to get the logged in user count in a Java web application that is running in a cluster?

I wrote a simple `HttpSessionListener` with a static field, but I suppose this doesn't work in cluster. I can see there is a Spring Security solution, but I read in some forums that this is still not ok in cluster.

The product in which I have to implement this user count is trying to be application server independent, currently we support Tomcat, Weblogic and JBoss. At the moment I need a solution for Weblogic 10.3 clusters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can maintain the counter in database which will work in cluster env.

Comment: if I increment the counter in `sessionCreated` and decrement in `sessionDestroyed`, then what about suddenly killed servers, who do not decrement the counters?

Comment: those are rare cases.. how do you handle the user's session data when a server goes down?? ..Possible solutions 1. you can use server's user handling capacity as benchmark to decrease the counter when server goes down. 2.  maintain counter in DB along with server ID.. say Server1 - >5, Server3->130..then decrease the counter when a server goes down.. hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

A simple tutorial to demonstrate how to determine active users / sessions in a Java Web Application.

```
package com.hubberspot.javaee.listener;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

@WebListener
public class OnlineUsersCounter implements HttpSessionListener {

private static int numberOfUsersOnline;

 public OnlineUsersCounter() {
  numberOfUsersOnline = 0;
 }

 public static int getNumberOfUsersOnline() { 
  return numberOfUsersOnline;
 }

    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {

     System.out.println("Session created by Id : " + event.getSession().getId());
     synchronized (this) {
   numberOfUsersOnline++;
  }

    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {

     System.out.println("Session destroyed by Id : " + event.getSession().getId());
     synchronized (this) {
   numberOfUsersOnline--;
  }

    }

}
```

Running the below servlet on three different browsers will provide output as : (see fig below)

```
package com.hubberspot.javaee;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebInitParam;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.hubberspot.javaee.listener.OnlineUsersCounter;

// @WebServlet annotation has a initParams field which takes
// in initialization parameters for a servlet.
// @WebInitParam annotation takes in a name and value for the
// initialization parameters for the current Servlet.

@WebServlet(name = "HelloWorldServlet" , urlPatterns = { "/HelloWorldServlet" }
, initParams = { @WebInitParam(name = "user" , value = "Jonty") })
public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {

 protected void doGet(
   HttpServletRequest request, 
   HttpServletResponse response
   ) throws ServletException, IOException {

  response.setContentType("text/html");

  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

  // sessionCreated method gets executed
  HttpSession session = request.getSession();

  session.setMaxInactiveInterval(60);

  try {
   out.println("<html>");
   out.println("<body>");
   out.println("<h2>Number of Users Online : "
      + OnlineUsersCounter.getNumberOfUsersOnline() 
      + "</h2>");
   out.println("</body>");
   out.println("</html>");
  } finally {
   out.close();
  }

 }

}
```

Output of the program :

1. Eclipse Browser ->

[image: Eclipse]

2. Firefox Browser ->

[image: Firefox]

3. Internet Explorer Browser ->

[image: IE]

4. Console Output ->

[image: Console]

For more: http://www.hubberspot.com/2013/09/how-to-determine-active-users-sessions.html