# Get Number of Active Users using Listener class

Tags: java, spring, session, servlets

I want the ***count of active users, not the active sessions*** like if I am logging in different browser or system using the same user credential. I should be getting count 1(NOt the count of sessions). I know the get the count of sessions but I am not able to get the count of users. I have written the code below for session counts ***Can I get user counts by adding some lines of code? If yes, Please help.***

**Note:** I have login Page where i am verifying user credentials then moving forward. The mentioned link is not going to solve my problem(Every Session will have its unique id ) I wanted to count no. of users. [User (session) count in cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935629/user-session-count-in-cluster)

```
public class SessionCounter implements HttpSessionListener {
    private List sessions = new ArrayList();


public SessionCounter() {
}

public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    HttpSession session = event.getSession();
    sessions.add(session.getId());

    session.setAttribute("counter", this);
}

public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    HttpSession session = event.getSession();
    sessions.remove(session.getId());

    session.setAttribute("counter", this);
}

public int getActiveSessionNumber() {
    return sessions.size();
}
}
```

Comment: @RafałSokalski I tried mentioned solution but it doesn't work. Because Session id will be unique for each new session that again concludes that it is counting session instead of users.

Comment: Do you use Spring Security ?

Comment: Yes, I use Spring Security. But My requirement is to do with listener class. I do not find any solution using the listener class I have seen the solution using spring security and database

Comment: @RafałSokalski If you think that this question is not duplicate then please mark as non-duplicate.

Comment: What about creating list with logged users. Then when you create session when user logged check if he is on that list if no then increment counter

Comment: I am looking for the solution where I get user details from a session and then I can store it in user data in a list.

Comment: If you want user details from session first you need to add him to session
[More information](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/41245-get-current-user-from-session)

Comment: @BalusC I am sure you can help me with this problem.

Comment: Did you check my comment ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried but I am getting anonymous users and the user is not getting invoked at the time of session creation.